# How to remove unused color from palette in ImgeEN

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-10-seattle

I am using ImageEN 5.2 (DCU Version) in Delphi XE 10.

I want to Remove UnUsed Colors from Color Table(or same Palette) and use this Code but this dont work :(

```
    procedure ConvertToOrdinal_8bit(PathToSave: string);
      var
        UsedColors: Integer;
        RGB_Palette: array of TRGB;
    begin
      with ImageEnView1 do
      begin
        UsedColors:= Proc.CalcImageNumColors;
        SetLength(RGB_Palette, UsedColors + 1);
        Proc.CalcImagePalette(RGB_Palette, UsedColors + 1);
        Proc.ConvertToPalette(UsedColors + 1, @RGB_Palette[0], ieOrdered);
        Refresh;
        Proc.Update;
        IO.Params.BitsPerSample := 8;
        IO.Params.SamplesPerPixel := 1;

        IO.SaveToFileBMP('c:\TestFile.bmp');
      end;
    end;
```

This Palette contain used colors and unused colors
[image]

and This Palette contain only used colors
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than removing unused colors I'd suggest setting the pixel format to ie8p then set the length of a TColorArray to the IEBitmap.PaletteLength then iterate through the IEBitmap.Palette to fill the TColorArray.

This will produce a list of the colors in the image.

```
uses ieview, imageenview, imageenproc, hyieutils, hyiedefs, exBitmaps, GraphUtil;

procedure TForm1.GetPaletteColors;
{ Fill TColorArray with palette colors. }
var
   i: Integer;
   iColorList: TColorArray;
begin
   ImageEnView1.IO.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
   { If the bitmap is not 8 bit paletted then convert it }
   if ImageEnView1.IEBitmap.PixelFormat <> ie8p then
      ImageEnView1.IEBitmap.PixelFormat := ie8p;
   SetLength(iColorList, ImageEnView1.IEBitmap.PaletteLength);
   { Add the colors to the TColorArray }
   for i := 0 to ImageEnView1.IEBitmap.PaletteLength - 1 do
   begin
      iColorList[i].Value := TRGB2TColor(ImageEnView1.IEBitmap.Palette[i]);
      iColorList[i].Name := '';
   end;
   { sort the colors by HUE - Optional}
   SortColorArray(iColorList, 0, 0, stHue, False);
end;
```

You can obtain excellent support from the developers of ImageEn if you need further assistance here:
http://www.imageen.com/ieforum/forum.asp?FORUM_ID=11

Comment: Thanks, but i dont set my palette to Bitmap file

Comment: @AliReza: Then perhaps you should edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking.